# Complex sentence - is this one correct?

Tags: sentence, complex-sentences

I think my sentence isn't perfectly correct, especially around the "**to learn**".

> App helping people with special needs (e.g. autism) to learn and
>   practice letters, maths, logical thinking, and other important skills.

I have 140 letter limit. I have Grammarly installed to test the sentence and it has found some errors but wants me to buy the subscription to it.

I'm not a native English speaker, so I'm asking for help. Thanks.

Comment: It's not a sentence.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm sorry, but what is it? It's translated from Slovak where it is considered as a sentence. It's a project description.